# DMs: In Rise of Tiamat, what would the metallic dragons think about PCs actions in the Hatchery?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dragons, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen, rise-of-tiamat

Spoilers for Rise of Tiamat and Hoard of the Dragon Queen. Beware!

In Rise of Tiamat the council score card and adjoining text discuss the different factions reaction to how the PCs acted in the Hatchery (HotDQ episode III). Later on there is an opportunity to sit in with representatives of the metallic dragons council. I would like to hear suggestions on how they would view the PCs actions regarding the eggs.

Edit after Markovs comment below: I’m not looking for an opinionated discussion but rather your suggestions based on the adventure and on 5e and Faerun lore.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Our site is not a traditional discussion forum, so idea generation discussion prompts don't fit well with our format here, unfortunately. However, we maintain [a curated list of discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where your question may be on topic.

Comment: I've added the [dnd-5e] tag, since *Rise of Tiamat* is an official published adventure for D&D 5th edition.

Comment: Rather than ask what they _would think_ (opinion-based), you might ask about what information _already exists_ in the adventure to draw on regarding their opinions (text-based), so that a DM could extrapolate to what they would think.  I think there is plenty of material there to give an answer that is a mix of objective and good-subjective.